# Data models using structs (value types in general) - How to keep everything in sync?

Tags: swift, struct

I hope this question is not too generalized or broad. But I've been trying to grasp this concept for the past week and I don't make any progress. I've read dozens of articles and answers on StackOverflow but nobody seems to address this properly. Everyone is always using the most basic models that don't intertwine at all (see example). It might just be me being stupid.

*I'm really struggling with understanding how a good data model works and how to implement it into an app*. I want a method that is consistent and convenient throughout the app. I have an example.

Let's say I want to create a data model like this:

```swift
struct Person {
    var name: String
}

struct Car {
    var name: String
    var owner: Person // Link to a car struct
}

struct Garage {
    cars: [Car] // Array of car structs. Usage: Maybe a list view that shows all cars
}
```

This covers some of my big problems using `structs` as data models:

- **References between models** - Structs are value types, referencing another model simply creates a copy of that model. Thus, I end up with multiple copies of the same data. What if that data changes? Or what if the reference itself changes (i.e. the owner of a car)? Observing a `Car` struct using, for instance, Apple's `Combine` framework doesn't really work because of this `owner` reference and the fact that it just is a copy of the original `Person`.
- **Arrays of models** - This seems to be even more tricky. I have to decide whether I want to use the array as a whole (i.e. for a list view) or if I need to use individual elements (i.e. passing a car to a detail view). When trying to keep everything synced it seems like I have to choose one of the two. Doing both at the same time looks impossible. I could create two separate models, each for its own use case but again, I end up having multiple copies of the same data. It just doesn't work.

  (To make it more clear: What I mean is I always have to decide between `Observe([cars])` and `[Observe(car)]`. Doing both doesn't seem to work.)

**How would I use this data model inside a project with multiple views like a "CarListView", "CarDetailView", "PersonDetailView", etc. without ending up with dozens different copies of my data that are all different?**

I really want to use `structs` because the code becomes so simple and beautiful. But it just seems to be really annoying and partially impossible. However, wherever I go people advice using `structs` over `classes` in most cases. The example looks like a fairly basic and normal use case. Is it not suitable for `struct` usage? Am I just stupid?

I'd be extremely grateful for any insight on this topic. This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Use Core Data. It can handle all relationships smoothly. However Core Data is based on classes.

Comment: Like vadian said, use Core data or some other database engine to store the data. The model structure you have is fine but the data stored in the properties is short lived and stored in memory. you shouldn't have a in-memory model that is getting updated from all sorts of places. load the model from the DB, do what you need to and save the changes, repeat wherever needed

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. The reason I originally started thinking about this is that I wanted to create independent and separated code. The idea was to have something you can plug into anything (like CoreData for instance) but that works on its own. This felt like the "correct" way. Maybe that presumption was just stupid?

Comment: On my past projects I used Realm as DB, I find that for small projects is much easer (lightweight) to use than core data. As for your observers, it does provide `NotificationToken` that allows you to observe changes on objects, queries and more.